# Override onTextChange listener of EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

I want to override on textchangelistener of EditText.

Example Scenarios:

**My input:** 123
**, Desired Output:** 1.23

**My input:** 12340
**, Desired Output:** 123.40

**My input:** 0
**, Desired Output:** 0.00

**My Input:** 1
**, Desired Output:** 0.01

Comment: When you use any of the awnsers, be carefull not to set the output as text for the `EditText`. Otherwise the listener will be called again and an endless loop will start.

Comment: Yes Sir, I have encountered that error lately. Its like stackoverflow error. Thanks for the heads up. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
float MyInput = 10;
String DesiredOutput = String.format("%.2f", MyInput ); // prints 10,00
```

If you want 123, 12340 printed as 1,23 , 123,40 you have to divide by 100

Answer (score 1):

you have to add Text

```
EditText editText;
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

add you logic inside onTextChanged method.

```
String output = s.subSequence(s.length() - 3,
                        s.length() - 1).toString();
                output = s.subSequence(0, s.length() - 3).toString()
                        .toString()
                        + "." + output;
                Log.i(TAG, "Out Put ::" + output);
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The first code works very fine. But the 2nd code doesn't work in some cases. Anyways thanks I have solved my problem now.